# convert this SQL to link Left Outer Join and a Case statement

Tags: linq

I am having problem converting this sql statement into Linq. It has a Left outer join and a case statement. I will try the answer given below.

```
SELECT  [job_required_document].[job_required_document_id]
  ,[document_name]
  ,[document_description]
     ,CASE WHEN dlink.job_required_document_id is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1  END    AS DocIsRequired
  FROM [dbo].[job_required_document]
          LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[job_description_document_link] dlink ON      job_required_document.job_required_document_id =     dlink.job_required_document_id 
                 AND dlink.job_description_id = @JobDescriptionId
```

**This is what i had done. But the docIsRequired  is coming 1 for all the records. I think the case statement is wrong.

```
             var query = from document in context.job_required_documents

                    join dlink in context.job_description_document_links.Where(q => q.job_description_id == job_description_id && q.job_description_id == job_description_id)
                    on document.job_required_document_id equals dlink.job_required_document_id into documentdlink

                    from q in documentdlink.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    select new Documents
                    {
                        job_description_id = job_description_id,
                        job_required_document_id = document.job_required_document_id,
                        document_name = document.document_name,
                        document_description = document.document_description,
                        docIsRequired = document.job_required_document_id == null ? 0 : 1
                    };
```

Comment: did you try something or just asked a question ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class with following details:

```
public class DocumentDetails
{
 public int docID {get;set;}
 public string docName {get;set;}
 public string docDesc {get;set;}
 public int docIsRequired {get;set;}
}
```

Now use this LINQ to fetch data into this class type's collection as mentioned below:

```
  List<DocumentDetails> documentDetialsList = (from document in  datacontext.job_required_document
    from dlink in datacontext.job_description_document_link 
    .where(x=> x.job_required_document_id ==  document.job_required_document_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where dlink.job_description_id == @JobDescriptionId
     select new {
        docID = document.[job_required_document_id], 
        docName = document.[document_name], 
        docDesc = document.[document_description],
        docIsRequired = dlink.job_required_document_id == null ? 0 : 1
       }).ToList();
```

Hopefully it would help...

Comment: HI shilpa i ran your Linq and it is doing a Inner Join but i am looking for  a Left Outer Join. I am also getting an error on the case statement. Name NULL does not consist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry null was uppercase that's why it wasn't working. But i am not able to figure out how to add the AND clause to the linq. If u see my sql there is an AND clause at the end.

Comment: The AND clause which you've used in your query can be used in where clause as you're comparing a parameter only...

Comment: Well shipla your query still gives 3 records. I was able to make some changes to get all the records but the Docrequired is coming as 1 for all the records. I have edited my linq query. take a look at it. i think the case statement is not working